# Why c header file is not generated using ANTLR works 1.5?

Tags: c, antlr3, antlrworks

I am trying to generate c code from ANTLR.grammar file, using antlrworks 1.5 (ANTLR 3.5) on windows, but it doesn't generate any header files, for example for sample.g it generates:

sample.tokens

sampleLexer.c

sampleParser.c

but not any header files and i can't figure out why.

The grammar what i am using now, is really simple for the sake of example:

```
grammar sample;

options 
{
language    = C;
}

rule1:
'ABC'   
;
```

I also get warnings such:

```
[12:39:44] warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser] 1:1 could not pass through undefined attribute filterMode
[12:39:44] warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser /genericParser /_sub721 /ruleAttributeScopeFuncMacro] 1:4 no such property or can't access: null.attributes
[12:39:44] warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser /genericParser] 155:5 no such property or can't access: null.apifuncs
[12:39:44] warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser /genericParser /rule /ruleDeclarations] 4:1 no such property or can't access: null.attributes
[12:39:44] warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser /genericParser /rule /ruleInitializations] 8:1 no such property or can't access: null.attributes
[12:39:44] warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /lexer /lexerRule /ruleDeclarations] 4:1 no such property or can't access: null.attributes
```

I have find an article about similar warnings on stackoverflow:
[numerous template errors generating OracleSQL grammar using Antlr-3.5-complete.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578292/numerous-template-errors-generating-oraclesql-grammar-using-antlr-3-5-complete-j)

(this is the only thing i have found out about this and i think it may not do anything about header files not being generated)

I would appreciate any help, i would like to generate some AST trees for my c++ project from some sql grammar i have made a long ago for java, but im stuck by this interesting issue.

Note:

I have also checked out all these articles:

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/FAQ+-+Getting+Started      //Starting guide
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=728              //guide on how to install ANTLR
(Although im using antlrworks, so i dont really need any other installation)
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29130826     //CplusTARGET  (It doesn't have support for AST trees, that i have read it on stackoverflow, thats why i am trying c target now)
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Using+the+ANTLR3+C+Target  //C TARGET
https://github.com/antlr/examples-v3                    //Examples for targets

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a side effect of a bug that's already been resolved for ANTLRWorks 1.5.1 (coming within the next ~week).

https://github.com/antlr/antlrworks/pull/9

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, i have tried to build the project in eclipse with target package, i get it to build successful, but when i start the antlrworks-1.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar i get a java exception right away. Can i somehow build the project and use it right now? Are there any alternative ways for windows to generate c files from the grammar?

Comment: I'm currently using it from eclipse as run, and as you have said the problem is gone, but can i build an uber jar from that? If yes, could you please give me some instructions?

Comment: I also could not build from the source.  But the jar I downloaded here did fix the header generation problem (for cpp anyway): https://github.com/antlr/antlrworks/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with 1.5.0
Using 1.5.2 solves the problem. You can download it here http://www.antlr3.org/works/