# Getting warning(24) : template error ... with antlr 3.5.2 generating C code on linux

Tags: c, templates, warnings, antlr3

I'm getting a bunch of warnings on linux (Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64) when I run antlr3.5.2 on a simple C program.  The program can be found here

https://github.com/antlr/examples-v3/tree/master/C/dynamic-scope.

It's Jim Idle's dynamic scope example. The only option it specifies is language = C .  When I compile the program with the C runtime, I don't get any errors and the program seems to run fine.  My question is whether the warnings indicate something I need to be concerned about.

Here's a sample of the warnings.

warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser] 1:1 could not pass through undefined attribute filterMode

warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser /genericParser /_sub45 /ruleAttributeScopeFuncMacro] 1:4 no such property or can't access: null.attributes

warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser /genericParser] 155:5 no such property or can't access: null.apifuncs

warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser /genericParser /rule /ruleDeclarations] 4:1 no such property or can't access: null.attributes

warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser /genericParser /rule /ruleInitializations] 8:1 no such property or can't access: null.attributes

If I try to use the output = template object, I get an error at code generation time.

error(10):  internal error: T.g : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such group file: org/antlr/codegen/templates/C/ST.stg

Thanks for any insights you may have,

Tony Passera

Comment: possible duplicate of [numerous template errors generating OracleSQL grammar using Antlr-3.5-complete.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578292/numerous-template-errors-generating-oraclesql-grammar-using-antlr-3-5-complete-j)

Comment: exactly. you can just ignore these template error warnings, or maybe try to fix the C generator.